# How to force use of Matlab (not MEX) in train function?

Tags: matlab, out-of-memory, neural-network

It is said, that Matlab's `train()` function can use either `MEX` or `Matlab` http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/optimize-neural-network-training-speed-and-memory.html

Also it is said, that memory reduction option works in case `train` function uses Matlab.

In my case `train()` function uses MEX but simultaneously I have out of memory error. Is it possible to force `train()` to use Matlab so that reduction option come into effect?

Comment: It might be helpful if you post an example of the specific out of memory error that you're getting. Have your tried specifying the `'reduction'` option to see if it might by chance force a switch to Matlab training?

Comment: Specific details for the problem are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25826914/error-using-eye-out-of-memory-while-training-neural-net-but-memory-looks-suffi

Comment: Can you put the location of the m-file version higher in the path? If they are in the same directory, search for something like "matlab shadowed functions," or something along those lines.